# How To login with Facebook using react?

Tags: reactjs

I have used "react-facebook-login" this package for login Facebook I
have got a response from Facebook and get token and then I forward
token to backend and the backend will be sending some JSON like

```
{userId: "1",sessionID: "2" successInd: "true"}
```

I want when I got a success is true then I go next page which is my dashboard page.

here is my code :-

```
class App extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = { isAuthenticated: false, user: null, token: ''};
    }

    logout = () => {
        this.setState({isAuthenticated: false, token: '', user: null})
    };

    onFailure = (error) => {
        alert(error);
    };

    twitterResponse = (response) => {
        const token = response.headers.get('x-auth-token');
        response.json().then(user => {
            if (token) {
                this.setState({isAuthenticated: true, user, token});
            }
        });
    };

    facebookResponse = (response) => {
        const tokenBlob = new Blob([JSON.stringify({access_token: response.accessToken}, null, 2)], {type : 'application/json'});
        const options = {
            method: 'POST',
            body: tokenBlob,
            mode: 'cors',
            cache: 'default'
        };
        fetch('http://localhost:4000/api/v1/auth/facebook', options).then(r => {
            const token = r.headers.get('x-auth-token');
            r.json().then(user => {
                if (token) {
                    this.setState({isAuthenticated: true, user, token})
                }
            });
        })
    };
```

Comment: you want to know how to redirect to dashboard page?

Comment: Have you setup routing to your project?